# Dynamic data grid row selection problem in Uipath

Tags: dynamic, datagrid, uipath

I was try to automate an Ui of a web based application using **UiPath RPA tool.**
In that UI, there is a **data grid** which can have any number of rows. When the page loads only the first row of the data grid appears. there is a button to add new row. I can edit cells of the row added manually. But the problem is when the UiPath process starts entering data in the cell of the row, it is only grabbing the cell of the first row in every iteration. Its not grabbing the the cell of the newly added row in the next iteration. Please note that I have tried to increment the row value using dynamic variable in **edit selector** option . But UiPath is still unable to grab that element. Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Depends on where to grab the data from. Some java application or a browser?

Comment: I am working on a java web base application. I am trying to grab the selector from browser.

Comment: Is that website free for everyone, so you can show?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [download data from website using uipath RPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992269/download-data-from-website-using-uipath-rpa)

Comment: @kwoxer I am sorry I couldn't reply earlier. No, the website is not free for everyone. I am trying to find out a way so that I can show it.

Comment: @Mads T, I have to try it out when I get back to office after weekend. I will let you know if these solutions works or not. Thanks a lot for your efforts